# XML String into a DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I am currently working with a webservice to pull a report about users in a remote support system.

After pulling my report and receiving the result, I am given the following string back by the method:

```
<report>
    <header>
        <field id="0">Source</field>
        <field id="1">Session ID</field>
        <field id="2">Date</field>
        <field id="3">Name</field>
        <field id="24">Technician Name</field>
        <field id="25">Technician ID</field>
    </header>
    <data>
        <row>
            <field id="0">Email</field>
            <field id="1">55037806</field>
            <field id="2">4/13/2010 2:28:06 AM</field>
            <field id="3">Bill Gates</field>
            <field id="24">John</field>
            <field id="25">1821852</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field id="0">Telephone</field>
            <field id="1">55034548</field>
            <field id="2">4/13/2010 12:59:44 AM</field>
            <field id="3">Steve Jobs</field>
            <field id="24">John</field>
            <field id="25">1821852</field>
        </row>
    </data>
</report>
```

After receiving this string, I need to take it and display the actual data in a datagridview.  I've tried putting it into an XMLDocument then reading that, but it seems to keep failing.  Just interested in another set of eyes :)  Application is written in C# in VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Linq to XML to build a `DataTable` with the column names from the XML file, then set that table as the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` :

```
        string xml = theWebService.TheMethod();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var queryHeaders =
            from field in doc.Root.Element("header").Elements("field")
            select new
            {
                Id = field.Attribute("id").Value,
                Name = field.Value
            };

        var headers = queryHeaders.ToDictionary(f => f.Id, f => f.Name);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (var kvp in headers)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(kvp.Value);
        }

        Func<XElement, DataRow> rowGenerator =
            element =>
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (var field in element.Elements("field"))
                {
                    string fieldId = field.Attribute("id").Value;
                    string columnName = headers[fieldId];
                    string value = field.Value;
                    row[columnName] = value;
                }
                return row;
            };

        var rows =
            from rowElement in doc.Root.Element("data").Elements("row")
            select rowGenerator(rowElement);

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView.DataSource = table;
```

Note that the code above only works if all fields have distinct names. If that's not the case, you might want to use the field ID as the `DataColumn` name, and change the headers of the DGV with the actual field names

Comment: Worked like a charm, I appreciate the guidance!

Comment: Actually, pulling longer reports yields multiple "header" entries in the XML.  Any thoughts on that anyone?  Thomas' suggestion works great when there's only one header being sent back.

Comment: Important to note that the <header></header> string is identical in each additional case in the XML, so maybe just parse out duplicate header entries in the string?

Comment: You can use `doc.Root.Elements("header").First()` to keep only the first `<header>` element